# FPGA Frequency Divider

Tags: fpga, pwm, vhdl, xilinx, frequency-divider

I need to design frequency divider from 50MHz to 200Hz using FPGA. I'm using Xilinx and the language that I used is VHDL language. I got stuck because I can't get the output. So, anyone can help me? Here I attach my code.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

entity FreqDivider is
port(
    clock   : in STD_LOGIC; -- 50 Mhz
    clear    : in STD_LOGIC;
      adjclk : out STD_LOGIC
);
end FreqDivider;

architecture Behavioral of FreqDivider is
signal adjfreq: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(17 downto 0) := "000000000000000000";
signal adjcntr: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(2 downto 0) := (others => '0');
signal adjclock : std_logic := '0';

begin

adjclk <= adjclock;

countClock: process(clock,clear,adjfreq)
begin
    if (clear = '1') then
            adjfreq <= "000000000000000000";
        elsif(clock'event and clock = '1') then
        if (adjfreq = "111101000010010000") then  --50MHz/250000=200Hz
                adjfreq <= "000000000000000000";
                adjclock <= '1';
            else adjfreq <= adjfreq+1;
                adjclock <= '0';
            end if;
    end if;
end process;

process(adjclock)
    begin
            if (adjclock 'event and adjclock ='1') then
                    if adjcntr = "101" then
                    adjcntr <= "000";
                    else adjcntr <= adjcntr+1;
                    end if;
            end if;
    end process;
end Behavioral;
```

Below is for testbench,

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;
USE ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
USE ieee.numeric_std.ALL;

ENTITY FreqDivider_tb IS
END FreqDivider_tb;

ARCHITECTURE behavior OF FreqDivider_tb IS 

-- Component Declaration for the Unit Under Test (UUT)

COMPONENT FreqDivider
PORT(
     clock : IN  std_logic;
     clear : IN  std_logic;
     adjclk : OUT  std_logic
    );
END COMPONENT;


--Inputs
signal clock : std_logic := '0';
signal clear : std_logic := '0';

--Outputs
signal adjclk : std_logic;

-- Clock period definitions
constant clock_period : time := 40 ns;  --50MHz
constant adjclk_period : time := 40 ns;

BEGIN

-- Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
uut: FreqDivider PORT MAP (
      clock => clock,
      clear => clear,
      adjclk => adjclk
    );

-- Clock process definitions
clock_process :process
begin
    clock <= '0';
    wait for clock_period/2;  --for 20ns signal is '0'.
    clock <= '1';
    wait for clock_period/2;  --for 20ns signal is '1'.
end process;

adjclk_process :process
begin
    adjclk <= '0';
    wait for adjclk_period/2;
    adjclk <= '1';
    wait for adjclk_period/2;
end process;


-- Stimulus process
stim_proc: process
begin       
  -- hold reset state for 100ms.
  wait for 40 ms;clear <= '1';  
    wait for 80 ms;clear <= '0';
  wait for clock_period*10;

  -- insert stimulus here 

  wait;
end process;

END;
```

Comment: You should add _why_ it isn't working? Is the output the wrong frequency? Are there errors at compile time? Etc.

Comment: There is no error at compile time, but for the ISIM simulator, I think there is something wrong with the waveform.

Comment: What do you think is wrong with the waveform? Since you are *toggeling* `adjclock` at a rate of 200 Hz the clock frequency of `adjclock` will in fact only be 100 Hz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, since unfortunately it isn't caught at compile time by your toolchain (which seems strange to me, but oh well):

Your `FreqDivider` component has an output port `adjclk`, and it is being driven by your `countClock` process. This is all very well and fine, no problem here.

However, your stimulus process has a signal called `adjclk` that is mapped to the `adjclk` port of your FreqDivider **and** this signal is being driven by a stimulus process `adjclk_process`. You cannot assign values to a signal that is being driven by a component. Most toolchains (at least, the ones I am familiar with) would identify this as bad, and complain loudly, but it seems your simulator only indicates this by an X or something in the output.

So, the solution: eliminate `adjclk_process`. It doesn't make sense to drive the output of a frequency divider that's supposed to be at 200Hz with a 25MHz signal.

Oh, and, as an aside, your math is a bit off on this line:

```
constant clock_period : time := 40 ns;  --50MHz
```

\$\frac{1}{50\text{MHz}} = 20\text{ns}\$, and each half-period would be 10ns, not 20ns.